# Mock testing an api for post method

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, mocking, tornado

I am trying to write a mock test for an api that someone else coded, and my duty is to test a module's post method. The module is written to do a job of a handler and it uses BaseHandler as super class.

What do i need is how/what to mock while writing the mock test for a http post method. Should I mimic a post request? Or make a real one? Or what else?

I am not allowed to share any codes, but the code uses tornado to make connection to localhost, mongodb for database read-write and is written using Python 3.6.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import mock

class Test(ApiTestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(send_sms, 'delay'):
    def test_send_sms(self, send_sms_mock):
        data = {}
        resp = self.client.post(self.url, data, format='json')
        assert send_sms_mock.call_count == 1
```

This is basic example to mock post

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. What is 'delay' doing?

Comment: this is if you call a celery method http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html

Comment: Please note if this helped you and was the answer to your question

Comment: Yes, the linked helps a lot, I will keep reading it further. Thanks!